# server side includes - use

Tags: apache, .htaccess, include, ssi

I am building some html templates the work has to be shared between 2 people, I want to create some common regions and include them in the files but the other users do not have php installed.

I have created a .shtml and used

- do people still use ssi includes?
- can I get the extensions to be .html?

Comment: Google "serve shtml as html" and see first link...

Answer (score 1):

SSI is still used for [simple apps](http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/Doc/User/SSI.html). Use the following to add `.html` as a file type for SSI:

```
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

**References**

- [mod_include.c](http://www.askapache.com/servers/mod_include.c.html)
- [Extending Apache](http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/3_3Extending_Apache.html)
- [Apache Modules](http://www.softpanorama.org/WWW/Webservers/Apache/modules.shtml)
- [Apache Security](http://www.softpanorama.org/WWW/Webservers/Apache/apache_security.shtml)
- [Using Server Side Includes](http://apacheweek.com/features/ssi)